# How well is mailto: supported?

Tags: javascript, html, email, cross-browser, mailto

I got an email saying that my mailto button wasn't working on Win8.

```
<input onclick="open('mailto:info@example.com?subject='+document.getElementById('subject').value,'_self');" type="button" id="btn" value="Email Me">
```

I'm wondering what kind of browser support exists for the 'mailto:' href. Furthermore, since I am triggering this via javascript, could a 'triggered' method be breaking this in windows8?

Comment: Couldn't you place this in an `a` tag with the `href='mailto:'`? That might solve the issue with `open()` not being standard.

Comment: @brenjt How is open non-standerd? Never heard that before. If it was, it would be mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open), wouldn't it? Besides, I'm not asking for a solution, I am asking for browser support.

Comment: `mailto:` has really good support. `window.open`, on the other hand, won’t work without JavaScript, is annoying, and is liable to be blocked by a popup blocker. That might be the case here.

Comment: @minitech Thanks. First comment/answer that tells me something.

Comment: Ah, and I had missed the part about it being triggered by JavaScript. Yes, a lot of browsers will only allow `window.open` if it’s triggered by a click.

Comment: `href="mailto:..."` is more likely to work than `window.open` in all browsers since there were browsers.  It is literally supported everywhere.  Newer browsers are even smart enough to open `mailto:` uris in gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the References section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto#References) of the Wikipedia article on the `mailto` URI scheme, I see that `mailto` was defined in [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368), which was published in July 1998. The spec was also updated in [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) in October 2010. Since `mailto` has been defined for so long, and I've never personally seen a modern computer that it doesn't work on, it probably has global support by now.

Comment: mailto might have been around for a long time, but there are many issues with its use, in particular varying support for features across browsers. Much better to use a form that is processed by a server.

Comment: But how does that count if you don't have an email to send the mail to? I.e. I want the user open up the mail client and fill address in himself...

Comment: Any updated on how well mailto url is supported or compatible with popular mail clients today?

Answer (score 1):

mailto is one of the oldest tags out there. It's the open part that's going to give you fits.

Why not style a link to make it look like a button and do this instead?

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com?subject=Something">Email me</a>
```

Now, I know that you want to put a subject in there, and that's cool. You might just want to do that with jQuery instead at that point, or creating a function that hrefs to mailto instead instead.

Comment: @Dude: The first sentence kind of implies an answer. Most old things (cf. `document.all`) stick around… forever.

Comment: Browser support was implied with first sentence.

Comment: Any updated on how well mailto url is supported or compatible with popular mail clients today?